# Position a div centrally using jquery window with

Tags: jquery, css

Can anyone help, there are similar questions already but none quite satisfy my issue.
I am building a parallax site http://www.bettondesignwork.co.uk/tim/Cayton2 and for the animations all divs and elements have to be absolutely positioned. This causes issues in different window sizes. Is there a way to set a div to be center horizontally using half the window with - half the div width?
I have this already but its not quite working

```
var h = $(window).height();
var w = $(window).width();
var shoptw = $('#shoptitle').css('height');


$('#shoptitle') .css({'left': ((w/2) - (shoptw/2) + "px")
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are after:

```
var h = $(window).height();
var w = $(window).width();
var shopth = $('#shoptitle').height();
var shoptw = $('#shoptitle').width();

$('#shoptitle') .css({'left': (w/2) - (shoptw/2), 'top': (h/2) - (shopth/2)});
```

Comment: Thats perfect thank you, and always so obvious once shown how lol!

Answer (score 0):

use `parseInt` method. This method convert sting to integer

```
var h = $(window).height();
var w = $(window).width();
var shoptw = parseInt($('#shoptitle').css('height'));


$('#shoptitle') .css({'left': ((w/2) - (shoptw/2) + "px")
});
```